# why inverse transform out of work in Python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm

I am practising the SVR and the module inverse_transform is out of wokr without raising any errors.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc1=StandardScaler()
sc2=StandardScaler()
x=sc1.fit_transform(x)
y=sc2.fit_transform(y)

print(x)
```

the output is:

```
[[-1.5666989 ]
[-1.21854359]
[-0.87038828]
[-0.52223297]
[-0.17407766]
[ 0.17407766]
[ 0.52223297]
[ 0.87038828]
[ 1.21854359]
[ 1.5666989 ]]
sc1.inverse_transform(x)
```

the output is:

```
array([[-1.5666989 ],
   [-1.21854359],
    [-0.87038828],
    [-0.52223297],
    [-0.17407766],
    [ 0.17407766],
    [ 0.52223297],
    [ 0.87038828],
    [ 1.21854359],
    [ 1.5666989 ]])
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there is something wrong with your code as the `StandardScaler` works correctly.

See the test below:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(20).reshape(-1, 1)
sc1=StandardScaler()
x_transform = sc1.fit_transform(x)
assert np.equal(sc1.inverse_transform(x_transform), x).all() == True
```